# Why "same size" pgfplots and datavisualization plots are so different?

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-datavisualization

Consider the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
x y
-2 7
-1 2
0 5
1 4
2 8
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization
[
scientific axes,
all axes={length=5cm},
x axis={label=x, attribute=x, min value=-2, max value=2},
y axis={label=y, attribute=y, min value=0, max value=10},
visualize as line,
]
data[read from file=test.csv, separator={\space}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=5cm,width=5cm,
             xlabel=x,xmin=2,xmin=-2,
             ylabel=y,ymin=0,ymax=10,
             enlargelimits=0,tick align=outside]
\addplot[no markers] table[x=x,y=y] {test.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

By setting both plots to have the same `width` and `height` one would expect to get if not exactly the same, at least a very (very) similar result. Instead this is the result:

[image]

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

How would one go about correcting this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the `width`/`height` of the `axis` environment specify the complete dimensions of the graphics, including the axis *labels*. (However, I could not confirm this in the pgfplots manual. *Edit:* See [Jake's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330932/why-same-size-pgfplots-and-datavisualization-plots-are-so-different#comment810962_330933) below for a source.)

To the contrary, `\datavisualization` really makes the axis (excluding the labels) the length you specified. This also seems to be supported by the TikZ manual ("the *x*-axis is then scaled and shifted so that it has the length specified").

Use `scale only axis` for pgfplots to get the same behaviour as for `\datavisualization`. (Thanks to Jake for pointing this out in the comments.)

Comment: You're right, `width` and `height` include the labels and titles by default (see section 4.10.1 of the current manual). You can set `scale only axis` to make the `width` and `height` apply to the axis lengths.

Comment: @Jake you are perfectly right! Adding `scale only axis` fixes it perfectly @Martin please add this to your answer so I can mark it as correct!

Comment: Done. I did not felt it to be necessary, though, as I consider the comments to be as valuable as the answers. And your question was not about a solution. :) Plus I don't like to re-state other people's answer, it feels like taking credit for them.

Comment: I understand and agree with you. But I feel it's better to have to solution in the answer itself. I'll add to the question a solution requirement, for the sake of consistency.