# How to set the height of a plot using pgfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I thought that the option `height` passed to `\nextgroupplot` is what i needed but it's not. As you can probably see in the picture, the second plot isn't two times the height of the first one. So how can I have the second plot two times the height of the first one?

**Bonus**: To be precise, what I would is that a distance of 1 along the y axis of the first plot is the same as a distance of 1 along the y axis of the second plot.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group size=1 by 2,
    vertical sep=12pt,
    group name=G},
  axis x line=center, axis y line=center,
  xmin = 0, xmax = 4.2
]
\nextgroupplot[
  width = \textwidth, height = 0.2*\textwidth,
  ymin = 0, ymax = 1.2
]
\draw (0,0) 
  -| (.75,1) -| (1,0) 
  -| (1.75,1) -| (2,0) 
  -| (2.75,1) -| (3,0) 
  -| (3.75,1) -| (4,0) 
  -| (4.75,1) -| (5,0);
\nextgroupplot[
  width = \textwidth, height = 0.4*\textwidth,
  ymin = -1.2, ymax = 1.2
]
\draw (0,1) 
  -| (.75,-1) -| (1,1) 
  -| (1.75,-1) -| (2,1) 
  -| (2.75,-1) -| (3,1) 
  -| (3.75,-1) -| (4,1) 
  -| (4.75,-1) -| (5,1);
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example_image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `unit vector ratio`. This makes sure that the y units have the same meaning in both plots. As mentioned by Torbjørn T. in the comments in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339221/121799), the height means height including everything, also tick labels.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group size=1 by 2,
    vertical sep=12pt,
    group name=G},
  axis x line=center, axis y line=center,
  xmin = 0, xmax = 4.2,unit vector ratio=2 1,width = \textwidth
]
\nextgroupplot[
  ymin = 0, ymax = 1.2
]
\draw (0,0) 
  -| (.75,1) -| (1,0) 
  -| (1.75,1) -| (2,0) 
  -| (2.75,1) -| (3,0) 
  -| (3.75,1) -| (4,0) 
  -| (4.75,1) -| (5,0);
\nextgroupplot[
  ymin = -1.2, ymax = 1.2
]
\draw (0,1) 
  -| (.75,-1) -| (1,1) 
  -| (1.75,-1) -| (2,1) 
  -| (2.75,-1) -| (3,1) 
  -| (3.75,-1) -| (4,1) 
  -| (4.75,-1) -| (5,1);
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]